# loop in loop creating 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I want to create a 2d array from divs with classes within divs with classes. This code gives me an array as far as I understood, but I can't access my objects in the array, whats wrong?

```js
var frames;
var myElements = [];
var animatedClasses = ["text", "splash"];

for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < animatedClasses.length; j++) {
        myElements[[i], [i, [j]]] = frames[i].getElementsByClassName(animatedClasses[j]);
    }
}
myElements[0,0].style.opacity = "0.5"; // DOESN'T WORK

}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
    <div class="splash"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>

<div class="frame">
    <div class="splash"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your final goal. Why are you trying to build this structure?

Comment: @Alf - You cant just demand answers. The language you are using is demanding. Remember we are here to help you not serve you. Please request not demand. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions.

Comment: `myElements[[i], [i, [j]]]` I believe you can't do this in javascript. The comma operator should return the last (right) element and ignore the first one. And why is that `j` surrounded in `[]`? Instead of all this, try `myElements[i][j]`.

Comment: Also, what isn't working? Feel free to post an error. We'll help you when you show more effort

Comment: Sorry if my language was demanding, I didn't do that on purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code

```js
var frames = document.getElementsByClassName('frame');
var myElements = [];
var animatedClasses = ["text", "splash"];

for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
    if(!myElements[i]) myElements[i] = Array(animatedClasses.length);
    for (var j = 0; j < animatedClasses.length; j++) {
        myElements[i][j] = frames[i].getElementsByClassName(animatedClasses[j])[0];
      }
 }
 console.log(myElements);
 myElements[0][1].style.opacity = "0.5"; // DOESN'T WORK
  myElements[0][1].style.color = "red";
```

```html
<div class="frame">
    <div class="splash"> Hello</div>
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>

<div class="frame">
    <div class="splash"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks a lot!